# Mypy, ignore types for remaining elements

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function like this

```py
def _parse(input_dict: dict) -> Tuple[int, str, ???]:
    entity = 3
    _id = "test"

    return (
        entity,
        _id,
        *super()._parse(input_dict),
    )
```

I know the types of the first two return values, and the remaining values are given by the return values of the parent class of the one with this function. Since the superclass has a similar `_parse` function, properly type hinting this will result in a ton of etries in the long run.

If we consider that this class has a subclass with the same function, its return value type hint would be `Tuple[subclass_param_1, subclass_param_2, int, str, ???]`, and will get longer and longer as we go deeper.

Is there a way of marking the rest of the parameters as unknown, assuming that we don't know how many parameters we will end up with?

Comment: With a function working as described, I don't think there is any point in typing it with anything more specific than simply `tuple`.

Comment: @matszwecja thanks for your feedback, I am trying to keep the codebase as type-hinted as possible, without going into madness

Comment: This doesn't make sense from typing perspective anyway, because such implementation violates LSP (subclass returns a tuple incompatible with superclass method return type).

Comment: Only `tuple[Any, ...]` is the common base for such tuples.

Comment: Additive signatures in subclasses is (IMO, generally, YMMV, etc) a strong indication that you should be using [composition rather than inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: @l0b0 could totally be, will look into it and try to improve my code. Here is a pastebin showing what the code is for if you want to take a look, and maybe guide me to the issue https://pastebin.com/eRcfXRpi